# Very fundamental doubt in integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a function of two variables $(x, y)$. Now I want to integrate $\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}$ with respect to x, i.e $$\int_a^b \frac{df(x,y)}{dx} dx$$
If y isn't a function of x then this is straight forward and the answer is $$\int_a^b \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} dx = f(b,y)-f(a,y)$$
But if $y$ is a function of $x$, then $$\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}$$
hence,
$$\int_a^b \frac{df(x,y)}{dx} dx=  \int_a^b \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dx +\int_a^b \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}dx$$
$$\int_a^b \frac{df(x,y)}{dx} dx= f(b,y)-f(a,y)+ \int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} dy$$
$$\int_a^b \frac{df(x,y)}{dx} dx= f(b,y)-f(a,y)+ f(x,y(b))-f(x,y(a))$$
After this step it has become very confusing as RHS shouldn't come out to be a function of $x$ and also if instead of solving like this I simply consider that $$\int_a^b \frac{df(x,y)}{dx} dx = \int_{f(a,y(a))}^{f(b,y(b))}df(x,y)$$
then the answer comes out to be totally different. Please tell me where I am wrong. This has made me embarrass a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y$ is a function of $x$, the statement
$$
 \int_a^b \frac{df(x,y)}{dx}dx = f(b,y(b)) - f(a,y(a))
$$
is always true, while it is false that, in general,
$$
 \int_a^b \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dx = f(b,y) - f(a,y),
$$
since even after having computed the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$, $y$ is still a function of $x$, and you must consider it while integrating.

EDIT:
I forgot to add that, if we suppose that the function $y(x)$ has an inverse function $x=\rho^{-1}(y)$, then

$$
 \int_a^b \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}dx = \int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} \frac{\partial f(\rho^{-1}(y),y)}{\partial y}dy \neq f(x,y(b)) - f(x,y(a)),
$$
since, as well as before, $x$ $does$ depend on $y$.

Furthermore,
$$
 \int_a^b \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}dx = \int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}dy 
$$
if and only if $y(x)$ has the inverse function over the domain $[a,b]$.

Comment: Your expressions of the form $g(a)-g(b)$ should be $g(b)-g(a)$ instead, i.e. you have sign errors in your first two equations.

Comment: Thanks J.G., I wrote too fast.